# A Triad of Pies

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Make the 41 integers between -20 and 20 (-20, -19, ..., 0, 1, ...20) using only the four basic arithmetical operations, square root, the floor function, and, Surprise Surprise, **exactly** 3 π’s. No more and no less. No other digits or symbols are allowed. You can use as many square roots and floor functions as you like. Parenthesis are allowed. **Unary minus sign is not allowed**. **Exponentiation is not allowed**. Anything not explicitly allowed is disallowed.

The floor function for x, written $\lfloor x \rfloor$, is equal to the greatest integer smaller or equal to x. For example, $\lfloor \pi \rfloor = 3$, $\lfloor \pi \times \pi \rfloor = 9$
and $\lfloor -\pi \rfloor = −4$.

Shorter is better (i.e. try to find expressions with the minimal number of +, -, $\times$, $\div$, $\lfloor\rfloor$ and $\sqrt{}$'s.)

Note: 20 and -11 to -20 are very challenging. (0 to 10 are fun)

Comment: Are we allowed to use things like $\pi^2$, or does that count as using a number ($2$) other than $\pi$?

Comment: No! exactly three pi's and that it.

Comment: I was expecting a puzzle about actual pies...

Comment: Isn't this [tag:open-ended]?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Retudin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/105664/5373) for $14,15,16,20$ and the inspiration necessary to find some others.

- > $-20=\left\lfloor\lfloor\pi\rfloor\div\left(\lfloor\sqrt{\pi}\rfloor-\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}\right)\right\rfloor$

$-19$ not found yet

- > $-18=\left\lfloor\pi\div\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}-\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}\right)\right\rfloor$
- > $-17=\left\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}\div\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}} - \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}\right)\right\rfloor$

$-16,-15,-14$ not found yet

- > $-13=\left\lfloor\pi\div\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}} - \sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)\right\rfloor$
- > $-12=\left\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}\div\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}}} - \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}\right)\right\rfloor$
- > $-11=\left\lfloor\pi\div\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}}} - \sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)\right\rfloor$
- > $-10=\left\lfloor\pi\div\left(\lfloor\sqrt{\pi}\rfloor-\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)\right\rfloor$

$-9$ not found yet

- > $-8=\lfloor\sqrt{\pi}\rfloor-\lfloor\pi\times\pi\rfloor$
- > $-7=\left\lfloor\sqrt{\pi}\div\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}} - \sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)\right\rfloor$
- > $-6=\lfloor\pi\rfloor-\lfloor\pi\times\pi\rfloor$
- > $-5=\lfloor\sqrt{\pi}\rfloor-\lfloor\pi+\pi\rfloor$
- > $-4=\lfloor\pi-\pi-\pi\rfloor$
- > $-3=\pi-\pi-\lfloor\pi\rfloor$
- > $-2=(\pi\div\pi)-\lfloor\pi\rfloor$
- > $-1=\lfloor\sqrt{\pi}\rfloor-\lfloor\sqrt{\pi}\rfloor-\lfloor\sqrt{\pi}\rfloor$
- > $0=\lfloor\pi\div(\pi\times\pi)\rfloor$
- > $1=\lfloor\sqrt{\pi}\times\pi\div\pi\rfloor$
- > $2=\lfloor\pi\rfloor-(\pi\div\pi)$
- > $3=\lfloor\pi\times\pi\div\pi\rfloor$
- > $4=\lfloor\pi\rfloor+(\pi\div\pi)$
- > $5=\lfloor\sqrt{\pi\times\pi\times\pi}\rfloor$
- > $6=\lfloor\pi+\pi\rfloor\times\lfloor\sqrt{\pi}\rfloor$
- > $7=\lfloor\pi+\pi\rfloor+\lfloor\sqrt{\pi}\rfloor$
- > $8=\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}\times(\pi+\pi)\rfloor$
- > $9=\lfloor\pi+\pi+\pi\rfloor$
- > $10=\lfloor\pi\times\pi\rfloor+\lfloor\sqrt{\pi}\rfloor$
- > $11=\lfloor\sqrt{\pi}\times(\pi+\pi)\rfloor$
- > $12=\lfloor\pi\times\pi\rfloor+\lfloor\pi\rfloor$
- > $13=\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}\times\pi\times\pi\rfloor$
- > $14=\lfloor(\pi+\sqrt\pi)\times\lfloor\pi\rfloor\rfloor$
- > $15=\lfloor\lfloor\pi\rfloor\times\lfloor\pi\rfloor \times\sqrt\pi)\rfloor$
- > $16=\lfloor\pi\times\lfloor\pi\rfloor \times\sqrt\pi)\rfloor$
- > $17=\lfloor\pi\times\pi\times\sqrt{\pi}\rfloor$
- > $18=\lfloor\pi\rfloor\times\lfloor\pi+\pi\rfloor$
- > $19=\lfloor\pi\times(\pi+\pi)\rfloor$
- > $20=\left\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}\div\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}} - \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}}}}\right)\right\rfloor$

Comment: Unary minus not allowed!!

Comment: @pepster :-/ you edited the question while I was answering ... OK, will try to fix this

Comment: Also, there is (for example) a shorter expression for 0.

Comment: @pepster Updated my answer. Still haven't found all the numbers, but now all are correct with no unary minuses.

Comment: _"@pepster :-/ you edited the question while I was answering"_ Very annoying, indeed.

Comment: similar to -17 = 2/(4-3) one can make -19 = 7/(7-5) or -19 = 3/(10-5). Now I wonder if any number is possible..

Answer (score 1):

As OP moved the goal posts half-way through I can't be bothered to fix this ...

> $0 = (\pi-\pi)\times\pi$
>  
>  $\pm 1 = \pm (\pi^{\pi-\pi})$
>  
>  $\pm 2 = \pm \frac{\pi+\pi}{\pi}$
>  
>  $\pm 3 = \pm \lfloor \pi+\pi-\pi \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 4 = \mp \lfloor \pi-\pi-\pi \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 5 = \mp \lfloor -\frac {\pi}{\pi}-\pi \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 6 = \pm \lfloor \pi \times \pi - \pi \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 7 = \mp \lfloor \pi - \pi \times \pi \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 8 = \pm \lfloor \frac {\lfloor \pi \rfloor^{\lfloor \pi \rfloor}} {\pi} \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 9 = \pm \lfloor \frac {\pi^{\lfloor \pi \rfloor}} {\pi} \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 10 = \mp \lfloor -\frac {\pi^{\lfloor \pi \rfloor}} {\pi} \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 11 = \pm \lfloor \frac {\pi^{\pi}} {\pi} \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 12 = \mp \lfloor -\frac {\pi^{\pi}} {\pi} \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 13 = \pm \lfloor -\frac {\lfloor \pi \rfloor^{\lfloor \pi \rfloor}} {\lfloor -\sqrt{\pi} \rfloor} \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 14 = \mp \lfloor \frac {\lfloor \pi \rfloor^{\lfloor \pi \rfloor}} {\lfloor -\sqrt{\pi} \rfloor} \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 15 = \pm \lfloor \frac {\lfloor \pi \rfloor^{\pi}} {\lfloor -\sqrt{\pi} \rfloor} \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 16 = \mp \lfloor \frac {\lfloor \pi \rfloor^{\pi}} {\lfloor -\sqrt{\pi} \rfloor} \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 17 = \pm \lfloor \pi\pi \sqrt{\pi} \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 18 = \mp \lfloor -\pi\pi \sqrt{\pi} \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 19 = \pm \lfloor \pi(\pi+\pi) \rfloor$
>  
>  $\pm 20 = \mp \lfloor -\pi(\pi+\pi) \rfloor$

Answer (score 1):

'missing' positives
14-16

> $14=\lfloor(\pi+\sqrt\pi)\times\lfloor\pi\rfloor\rfloor$

> $15=\lfloor\lfloor\pi\rfloor\times\lfloor\pi\rfloor \times\sqrt\pi)\rfloor$

> $16=\lfloor\pi\times\lfloor\pi\rfloor \times\sqrt\pi)\rfloor$

20

> $20 = \lfloor\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt\pi)) / (\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt\pi))) - \sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt\pi))))) \rfloor) $

Answer (score 0):

The missing numbers (including some Rand also solved in the meantime)

> $-9 = \lfloor \lfloor \sqrt{\pi} \rfloor - \pi \rfloor \times \lfloor \pi \rfloor$
>  $-10 = \lfloor \lfloor \lfloor \sqrt{\pi} \rfloor - \pi \rfloor \times \pi \rfloor$
>  $-12 = \lfloor\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\lfloor \sqrt{\pi} \rfloor - \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}} \rfloor$
>  $-13 = \lfloor \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\lfloor \pi \rfloor - \pi}\rfloor$
>  $-14 = \lfloor\frac{\lfloor \sqrt{\pi} \rfloor}{\lfloor \sqrt{\pi} \rfloor - \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}}} \rfloor$
>  $-15 = \lfloor \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}}}}}}}} - \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}}}\rfloor$
>  $-16 = \lfloor \frac{ \sqrt{\pi} }{ \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}}} - \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}}\rfloor$
>  $-17 = \lfloor \frac{\lfloor \pi \rfloor}{ \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}  - \sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}\rfloor$
>  $-18 = \lfloor \frac{\pi}{ \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}} - \sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}\rfloor$
>  $-19 = \lfloor \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}}}}}}}}- \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}}} \rfloor$
>  $-20 = \lfloor\frac{\lfloor \pi \rfloor}{\lfloor \sqrt{\pi} \rfloor - \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}}}} \rfloor$

Answer (score -1):

Those are "minimal" expressions. (some of you posted alternate forms with equal number of operations, but others were not minimal).

> [image: 1]

Comment: Would it be possible to type these out instead of just showing a picture?